# jQuery: При нажатии получить текст отдельных селекторов

Tags: jquery

Хочу получить текст отдельных селекторов, в моем случае всегда только первый селектор выводится: `<div id="nick">Текст1</div>`, а нужно чтобы если нажал на третью: `<div id="nick">Текст3</div>`, то вывел текст: Текст3

Код такой:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<div id="nick">Текст1</div><br><br>
<div id="nick">Текст2</div><br><br>
<div id="nick">Текст3</div><br><br>
<div id="nick">Текст4</div><br><br>
<div id="nick">Текст5</div>

<script>

jQuery('div#nick').on('click',function(){jQuery('div#nick').text().index()}){
console.log();
}

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте $(this) внутри jquery функции

```
jQuery('div#nick').on('click',function() {
    $("#result").html($(this).text())
})
```

[демо на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u3Lanpuv/)

Comment: А в IE всё равно не заработает. Там финт `div#nick` не проходит. Ну или раньше не проходил.

Comment: Ссылка на демо ведёт не на демо...

Comment: ссылку поправил. Про ie врать не буду, не знаю :(